# WCF namedpipe binding - time out error

Tags: c#, wcf

I am creating WCF application in which,

- client is built in x64 bit platform
- server is built in x86 bit platform
- communcation between two is using Namedpipe binding.

Server: it is console application which talk to MS Access database, and send the result of executed command
Client: it is winform application which talk to server and sends a request [ a select query `SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME`]

- client calls function of server [for ex: public List Foo(string query)]

Problem: When the query is executed on server side with small data [say 6000 rows] then the data is send to client in format List
with no problem. As the size of data is grows large [say 10,00,000 rows] then the client gives an error which is mentioned below.

Error : The operation cannot be completed because the pipe was closed.  This may have been caused by the application on the other end of the pipe exiting.

WHAT MIGHT BE THE PROBLEM ?

Please reply if someone needs more explaination.

-use below link to find the code
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/166598/wcf-namedpipe-binding-time-out-error.aspx

Comment: Please don't link code... links die and don't help people once they're dead.  Copy and paste relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you wil need to increase the Quotas and Buffer sizes both on server and client side:

Example:

```
  <netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding name="Binding1" 
             maxBufferSize="655360" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="655360">
       <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
             maxStringContentLength="2147483647" 
             maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
             maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
             maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" /> 
    </binding>
  </netNamedPipeBinding>
```

Answer (score 0):

Named pipe bindings can only be used where the service and client are hosted on the same physical machine (I thought anyway?) - what are the timeout values you've got?

Comment: -use below link to find the code
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/166598/wcf-namedpipe-binding-time-out-error.aspx

Comment: the application is running on same physical machine. only the application is built using 64 & 86 bit.